# How to SET jsonb_column = json_build_array( string_column ) in Sequelize UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I'm converting a one-to-one relationship into a one-to-many relationship. The old relationship was just a foreign key on the parent record. The new relationship will be an *array* of foreign keys on the parent record.

(Using Postgres dialect, BTW.)

1. First I'll add a new JSONB column, which will hold an array of UUIDs.
2. Then I'll run a query to update all existing rows such that the value from the old column is now stored in the new column (as the first element in an array).
3. Finally, I'll remove the old column.

I'm looking for help with step 2: writing the update statement that will update all rows, setting the value of the new column based on the value of the old column. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to express this SQL query using Sequelize:

```sql
UPDATE "myTable"
SET    "newColumn" = json_build_array("oldColumn")
-- ^^ this really works, btw
```

Where:

- newColumn is type JSONB, and should hold an array (of UUIDs)
- oldColumn is type UUID
- names are double-quoted because they're mixed case in the DB (shrug)

Expressed using Sequelize sugar, that might be something like:

```js
const { models } = require('../sequelize')

await models.MyModel.update({ newColumn: [ 'oldColumn' ] })
```

...except that would result in saving an array that contains the string "oldColumn" rather than an array whose first element is the value in that row's `oldColumn` column.

My experience, and the Sequelize documentation, is focused on working with individual rows via the standard instance methods. I could do that here, but it'd be a lot better to have the database engine do the work internally instead of forcing it to transfer every row to Node and then back again.

Looking for whatever is the most Sequelize-idiomatic way of doing this, if there is one.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "*The new relationship will be an array of foreign keys on the parent record.*" - don't. You cannot put foreign key constraints on the values inside arrays.

Comment: Good advice, although in this case the keys come from an entirely different database, and so I won't be able to enforce the relationship at the DB layer regardless. And I still want to know how to express this kind of query.